# Issues installing firebase tools, no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

Just want to start off by saying I am pretty much totally new with the command line outside of the basics of downloading packages so if you are able to explain as if you were talking to a 5-year old that would be great.

Im Trying to install the Firebase command line tools via:

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

And this seems to have worked just fine but upon trying to run the firebase login command (as seen in step two here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux), im getting the following error:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/tobmuldo/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/firebase
```

I have no idea how paths work so any help trying to get this figured out would be great, I'm on MacOS and am using yarn as my main package manager. All help is appreciated more than you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake on my part, turns out that I was using the wrong node version.

My project is using node 10 to accommodate the firebase functions but I was installing while using a modern node version.

running:

```
nvm use 10
```

before using the install command fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off installing it via `npm install -g firebase-tools`. Same thing happened to me yesterday so I went with that option instead.